Problem with POST method ([FromBody] dynamic ...) on dotNet 8.0 API Server
I've decided to convert my React + dotNet 3.1 API app to a dotNet 8.0 one. The old one is working fine, but I want to move  to a Kube Container and 3.1 is no longer supported by MS. Nothing outstanding, a rather straightforward app. On the second day I ran into this completely unexpected problem with the POST method with dynamic args passed. Dynamic is rather a point of contention for me. It simplifies things tremendously and, honestly, I did not try to see if the explicit args would work. Why, because it works in dotNet 3.1!
Here's how to replicate it:
Tool:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.10.5
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.10.5+35122.118
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032
Create a new project: React and ASP.NET Core; A full stack application with React project and a backend ASP.NET Core. .NET8.0 (Long Term Support)

Start it. You should see windows for the Demo and Swagger.

Open up the file …\ReactApp1.Server\Controllers\WeatherForecastController.cs. Add the below function and save the file. The purpose here is to create a post method.
[HttpPost(Name = "PostWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Post([FromBody] dynamic args)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}


Restart the project to see POST added in the Swagger:


Put a break point on the line containing '{' or 'return'. Execute "Try it out" and verify that the break point worked and you can see the value of args.

Start the Postman. Connect to API https://localhost:7146/WeatherForecast and verify that GET is working.

Change Postman to POST, select Body, JSON. Enter any valid Jason object:
{
"id": 0,
"name": "string",
"isComplete": true
}

Send and verify the return is the same as in Get.

In the Postman generate a code snippet for 'JavaScript - Fetch'. Should look like this:
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("test", "test");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

const raw = JSON.stringify({
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "isComplete": true
});

const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: "follow"
};

try {
  const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7146/WeatherForecast", requestOptions);
  const result = await response.text();
  console.log(result)
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
};


Open up the file …\reactapp1.client\src\App.jsx. Scroll down to the function "async function populateWeatherData()", add another function and save the file. Content of the function is the code snippet:
async function populateWeatherData_2() {
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("test", "test");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "isComplete": true
    });

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: "follow"
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7146/WeatherForecast", requestOptions);
      const result = await response.text();
      console.log(result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    };


In this function put a break point on the first line (to verify that it is used) and another one in the catch section.

In App function (file …\reactapp1.client\src\App.jsx) point to a newly created 'populateWeatherData_2' like this:



useEffect(() => {
    populateWeatherData_2();
}, []);

 ```


Save and refresh the demo page. Verify that the above break point works. At this point execution does not reach the API: it does not hit the break point in API and the Demo page does not contain the previous return.

The server responds correctly to POST when the Postman is used. The Postman was useful for the POST function creation, but I do not trust it any more, because it looks like it uses CURL.
I used both 'fetch' and 'Axios' and tested the code with VSC - same result. If you try to dig debug deeper you can see that the request reaches the API and breaks in one of the methods. I am not sure if it is MS bug or I am missing something.
Did anybody ran into this? Any suggestions?

I noticed that  you have [FromHeader] dynamic args in your controller, but in reqquest option you have body: raw,. Where you want to put your parameters?

Here's my test result based on your steps. Firstly, my react app hosts on 5173 port and API hosts on 7176 port. No matter I use [FromHeader] dynamic args or [FromBody] dynamic args, I can call the POST endpoint successfully. And just like what you can see in screenshot below, the url for the post method is https://localhost:7176/WeatherForecast but not http://localhost:5173/WeatherForecast/PostWeatherForecast.

If I used const response = await fetch("weatherforecast" , requestOptions); to send the API in populateWeatherData_2 I can call the API endpoint successfully. But since the body: raw, in defined in request body, we can't get it in dynamic args as it's defined to get data from request header. By the way, the request sent by fetch is https://localhost:5173/weatherforecast, we can see it in browser console window. I just followed what the origin populateWeatherData() did.

If I want to  use const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7176/WeatherForecast" , requestOptions);, I will get CORS error, if I set the CORS policy in the API project, I can call the API endpoint too. In the meantime, even if I set CORS policy, if I set the url as https://localhost:7176/WeatherForecast/PostWeatherForecast, I will get 405 error.


About why "https://localhost:5173/weatherforecast" can work but "https://localhost:5173/WeatherForecast" can't work, we can see the proxy configuration in vite.config.js. We can see - Update vite.config.js to set up proxying and certs. in the CHANGELOG.md file.

As I said I, did not have problems with Postman and Swagger, it is both 'fetch' and 'axious' that do not reach API method in .Net 8.0 but in the .Net 3.1 it works as expected.
I want to use FromBody, but do not mind either FromHeader or FromQuery. When I use FromBody it does not hit PostWeatherForecast from the React app. That's the rub - React request.

My concerns are 1. does the url is correct? In my test, if I add your controller method into my controller, the action endpoint is /WeatherForecast but not /WeatherForecast/PostWeatherForecast, you just said do not reach API method but there's no error message or error code. 2 does the default populateWeatherData() can hit the action in default controller? You create a new populateWeatherData_2() function and use it to call the newly created post endpoint, I want to know whether the Get request can work or not, it can help check whether the proxy setting is changed or not.

I created a new react + .net 8 just like what you described, and what I want to share with you contains 2 parts, one is that I used const response = await fetch("weatherforecast" , requestOptions); which is similar to the default populateWeatherData() function did, it used the react proxy setting and can work well in my side. Another part is that I used const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7176/WeatherForecast" , requestOptions); , this requires me to add CORS policy in the .net API project then it could work.

The API url used in your code snippet is "http://localhost:5173/WeatherForecast/PostWeatherForecast",, since you are also creating a new project so that I'm afraid the port 5173 is for the react app, but I think you should use the port for API project instead. In the mean time, if you didn't change the route rule, the endpoint for the newly added POST request should be https://localhost:port_for_api_project/WeatherForecast instead of /WeatherForecast/PostWeatherForecast.

If I misuderstand your issue, may I know more about did not get the server method? Is there any error message in the console window of the browser? We are getting CORS error/404/405 or something else? In my post, I shared the error I faced after following the steps you gave and my solution for the errors I met.

Yeah, not clear!
These are steps I follow


Use Postman to connect to the API and pass any valid Json. Verify it stops on the break point;


Use Postman to generate a code snipped to paste it in the function that sends the request to API.


Place break points in:
Javascript code in App.jsx and
The [HttpPost(Name = "PostWeatherForecast")] method in the Controller:  public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase


Refresh the Demo page to see if the break points stop execution in both Javascript and API



I should've described the steps in the question as I did in my last comment. Apologies ...

Hmmm.... sorry I find it difficult to communicate effectively with you, and I feel really sorry about this. May I know Is there any error message in the console window of the browser? We are getting CORS error/404/405 or something else?. You test your react project in the browser, may I know whether you got any error message in the console window? Press F12 to open the DevTool of the browser, and you will see a window with many menus, one of the menus is Console. You can see errors inside the page.

May I know, whether http://localhost:5173/WeatherForecast/PostWeatherForecast is the url you used in POSTMAN and call your web API successfully? May I know whether you tried to use const response = await fetch("weatherforecast" , requestOptions); instead of your const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5173/WeatherForecast/PostWeatherForecast",requestOptions); and the test test result if you test it?

I found extremely problematic working with dynamic as endpoint method param in ASP.NET - only way to get information out of it was to use such code (example done with Minimal APIs, but can be used in controllers as well):
app.MapPost("/dynamic", async ([FromBody] dynamic body) =>
{
    var jsonElement = (JsonElement)body;
    foreach (var prop in jsonElement.EnumerateObject())
    {
        var propName = prop.Name;
        var propValue = prop.Value.GetString();
        // You could use other methods such as GetByte(), etc.
        // to get other values.
    }
})
.WithOpenApi();


I find dynamic rather convenient. I use a simple function to get the values:
    private bool DynValue(object args, string key, out string val)
    {
        val = "";
        JObject pars = JObject.Parse(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(args));

        foreach (var p in pars)
        {
            if (p.Key.Equals(key)) { val = p.Value.ToString(); }
        }
        return (val != "");
    }

Use of which looks like this:
if (!DynValue(args, "user", out user_name)) { return Unauthorized(); }
